# How to send message to activemq payload as in the form of long(datatype)?

Tags: .net, activemq-classic, nms, apache-nms

I am using .NET 3.5 to send message to active mq and i have a java listener which process these messages from the queue.

Header contains

```
userId - long
type - string
isAdd-bool
```

Listener is expecting payload to be of datatype long. So i should send datatype long in payload.

Here is the code that i am using to post message to active mq.

```
string payLoad = "123";    
IConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
                    using (IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
                    {
                        using (ISession session = connection.CreateSession())
                        {
                            IDestination destination = Apache.NMS.Util.SessionUtil.GetDestination(session
                                , "Message.AddUser");
                            using (IMessageProducer producer = 

session.CreateProducer(destination))
                            {
                            // Start the connection so that messages will be processed.
                            connection.Start();

                            //here i need to pass payload as datatype "long"
                            ITextMessage request = session.CreateTextMessage(payLoad);
                            request.Properties["userid"] = 123;
                            request.Properties["type"] = "USER";
                            request.Properties["isAdd"] = true;
                            producer.Send(request);

                        }

                    }
                }
```

Currently as per the code, i am sending string as payload.

```
 ITextMessage request = session.CreateTextMessage(payLoad);
```

How can i change this code to send payload as data type long? i tried to send payload as object. But i am getting an error when listener picks this message. Error: Invalid stream header is corrupted.

As per the comment, i used IStreamMessage

```
            int userId = 123;
            IStreamMessage message = session.CreateStreamMessage()
            message.WriteInt64((long)idToUpdate);
            message.Properties.SetLong("userId", (long)userId);
            message.Properties.SetString("type", "USER");
            message.Properties.SetBool("isDelete", true);
```

Then i looked at tomcat logs and this is what i could see, Header is missing in this. I have only Payload

```
[Payload=ActiveMQStreamMessage {commandId = 5, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:XXXXX-60790-
stamp=1400070001928, jms_redelivered=false, userId=123, type=USER, jms_messageId=ID:XXXXX-60790-635356865723233336-0:0:1:2:1}]
```

As this was not working, i tried using ITextMessage.

```
int userId = 123;
ITextMessage request = session.CreateTextMessage();
request.Text = idToUpdate.ToString();
request.Properties["companyId"] = (long)userId;
request.Properties["type"] = "USER";
request.Properties["isDelete"] = true;
```

Here is what i could see in the log.

```
[Payload=46][Headers={timestamp=1400072608501, id=dde638d2-4036-4e81-a3c8-97937ac11087, isDelete=true, jms_timestamp=1400072608280, jms_redelivered=false, userId=1, type=USER, jms_messageId=ID:xxxx-53593-635356892076410652-0:0:1:2:1}]
```

I am using Sprint Integration and listener is expecting List as the input parameter

```
public void updateUser(Message<List<Long>> message) {
    Long userId = (Long) message.getHeaders().get("userId");    
    for (Long userId : message.getPayLoad()) { // exception is thrown here "Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long"
        //doing somethign here with userid
    }
}
```

How can send payload which is of long datatype?

Comment: That last bit sounds like a bug in the StreamMessage, are you using the latest version of the library?  Have you tried a BytesMessage instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response Tim, I will try with BytesMessage and keep you posted on the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ObjectMessage instead of TextMessage.

See here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/ObjectMessage.html

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple choices in how you implement that.

- You can use a BytesMessage and use the read / write methods that operate on longs but there is no type checking there so make sure your client's all do the right thing.
- You can use a StreamMessage which has read / write for long and will check types and do some type conversions as needed if you want.
- You can use a MapMessage and store the long in a key / value mapping.
- You can parse the text of the TextMessage to a long using standard Java code.

You can't really use ObjectMessage between .NET and Java, nor would you want to in this case since it's a simple primitive type.

Comment: I stand corrected. didn't notice that the client was Java

Comment: IStreamMessage message = new ActiveMQStreamMessage();
            message.WriteInt64((long)idToUpdate);//1
            message.Properties.SetLong("userId", (long)userid);//123
            message.Properties.SetString("type", headerType.ToString());// USER
            message.Properties.SetBool("isDelete", isDeleteAction);//true
When i look at my payload, 
[Payload=ActiveMQStreamMessage {commandId = 5, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:XXXXX-60790-
stamp=1400070001928, jms_redelivered=false, userId=1, type=USER, jms_messageId=ID:XXXXX-60790-635356865723233336-0:0:1:2:1}]
I dnt hve headers

Comment: I don't know what's that's supposed to mean.

Comment: @TimBish, i have edited my question with response to your reply. Could you please look at it?